# About the ExtReact7.2.0 License

Tags: extjs, extreact

I want to use the ExtReact components for my enterprise application.
Is it free to use ? if yes, how to set it up for the project.
PS : https://github.com/sencha/ext-react this code is open but i can't find out how to put it to work for my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not free. You can try with 30 days free but the cost is around $800.

```
ExtReat code for the grid
<Grid title="Users" store={this.store}>
    <Column text="Name" dataIndex="name"/>
    <Column text="Email" dataIndex="email"/>
 </Grid>

Extjs code for the grid
{
  xtype: 'grid:
  column: [{
    text: 'Name',
    dataIndex="name"
  },
  {
    text: 'Email',
    dataIndex="email"
  }
  ]
}
```

If you want to really use ExtJs then use plan ExtJS. Only difference is Extjs working on JSON and Extreact is working based on HTML attribute(config)